# Two apparently equal test cases coming back failed. What can cause that?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

Below are a few lines from my test case.  The first assertion comes back as false, but why?  The second does not.

```
  result=Parser.parse_subject(@@lexicon.scan("kill princess"), Pair.new(:noun, "bear"))
  assert_equal(Parser.parse_subject(@@lexicon.scan("kill princess"), Pair.new(:noun, "bear")),Parser.parse_subject(@@lexicon.scan("kill princess"), Pair.new(:noun, "bear")))
  assert_equal(result,result)
```

Here is the actual error:

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

.F.

Finished tests in 0.004000s, 750.0000 tests/s, 1750.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_parse_subject(ParserTests) [test_fournineqa.rb:30]:
Sentence:0x21ad958 @object="princess", @subject="bear", @verb="kill" expect
ed but was
Sentence:0x21acda0 @object="princess", @subject="bear", @verb="kill".

3 tests, 7 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have defined a `class Sentence` but have provided no way to compare two `Sentence` instances, leaving `assert_equal` comparing the identities of two objects to discover that they are not the same instance.

A simple fix would be something like:

```
class Sentence
  def ==(sentence)
    @subject == sentence.subject and
      @verb == sentence.verb and
      @object == sentence.object
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first assertion compares two different objects with the same content whereas the second assertion compares two identical objects. Apparently `equal` in this context means "identical objects". (Check the implementation.)